# Long polling and MySQL

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a long polling script:

1. When the page is loaded set the `timestamp` to 0.
2. If there wasn't any `timestamp` or it equals to 0 it means that the page is fully reloaded, So I will get the *10* newest posts or something similar.
3. From the PHP script I echo out the `timestamp` which equals the server timestamp.
4. Now I start the long polling script and pass the `timestamp` as a GET parameter and fetch  the posts after that `timestamp`.
5. And then loop again.

So this is my plan. Is this a good plan or are there better ways to do this **with PHP**?

Thanks!

Comment: Fine, now we can understand something of what you want to do. So your goal is to "update" some content on the page automatically, right? is it?

Comment: The step #4 is not clear. How are you going to fetch the new data after `timestamp`?

Comment: Yeah, in this case, Get the new posts.

Comment: Then you shouldn't do that with PHP only. PHP is a server side language. I would rather go with javascript and update the content every time it changes. Example: perform an AJAX request every X seconds, fetch the database and check if there is something new. If there is something new, send it to the client through PHP and update the section you want to. You can't pretend to do that with PHP only, it will be extremely slow and you will be forced to reload each time:P

Comment: Using SQL: "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE posted_date >= :timestamp".

Comment: @Akar: so let's say nothing was added and you immediately get 0 rows. What's next?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, With JavaScript, not just PHP.

Comment: Well, then show something :). In your question you're saying: **Is this a good plan or are there better ways to do this with PHP?**. So, answering to your question: I didn't get your plan, but I'm pretty sure the most efficient way to do this is by using ajax requests.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I meant just PHP as a server-side language, Because you can do the same with Node.js

Comment: Well, using nodejs for such a task seems a little bit eccessive to me. For such an application you wouldn't really need a "real time" javascript library, you can just go on with ajax and perform some requests to the server, without polling it every millisecond maybe :)

Comment: Long polling is different than short-polling, Long polling opens a connection for like 20 second if there aren't any results, Then it will die and start the long-polling again, Short polling is what you're saying.

Comment: @Akar: we know what long polling is. You haven't explained what you will do after your immediate sql query returns 0 rows.

Comment: Anyway, check this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (and use ajax for such a task). Just an idea here: make an ajax request to a PHP script and pass it the last "news" id you have: check it with PHP and check if there are newer ones. If there are, echo from php the new content and paste it in the news section with jQuery (on the ajax success callback). Once you did it, just feel free to use the comfort `setInterval` javascript function, to execute the ajax request every X seconds.. And you're done :).

Comment: Sorry, after the SQL query returns 0, I output a message that says `no-results` or something similar, And in JavaScript I will set an If condition, If there was any results I will output it, If not then start the long polling again.

Comment: @briosheje: OP mentioned several times they need long-polling explicitly, not sure why you propose something that is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Akar: you DON'T need long polling for such a task. I don't think you really need to poll the server for such a long time for such a basic task.

Comment: @Akar: so how is it a long polling if you return immediately?

Comment: @zerkms: I propose that because he doesn't need a long polling here, that's why :)

Comment: @briosheje: "because he doesn't need a long polling here" --- what's wrong with long polling for this task?

Comment: Why on earth would you poll the server forever for fetching something new? It doesn't really matter here after how much time you're updating the content. By the way the route to perform a long polling is almost the same (talking about code) as the short one. You just call the same function infinitly and stress the server. that's a good way to do such a task, right?

Comment: @zerkms From where I said it will return immediately?

Comment: @briosheje: "Why on earth would you poll the server forever for fetching something new?" --- because that's how you could build a responsive application without using websockets "You just call the same function infinitly and stress the server. that's a good way to do such a task, right?" --- please elaborate "stress". For a second - it's the same what you recommend.

Comment: @Akar: how would you implement it then? So you've sent a long-polling HTTP request, there on the server you perform an sql query that returns 0 rows. What next?

Comment: @zerkms: you perform a request, get the response and perform the request again. Isn't that stressing or am I losing something? :P

Comment: good! geek fight is always productive and informative, why go for ajax, running a loop and calling the server infinity ? why not just use some real time library and when there is a new content update the page?

Comment: @briosheje: that's what **you** proposed using `setInterval` didn't you?

Comment: Meh, Naveed Ahmad is right, let's stop discussing about what's good and what's bad. @Akar: check this and choose the way you prefere: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery :).

Comment: @Naveed Ahmad: long polling has its usage, eg. as a backup for clients that cannot work through websockets

Comment: @briosheje: that article doesn't cover server-side part, which is the most tricky one (and which the OP is in stuck with). To be precise: client-side part is *trivial*

Comment: @zerkms yep but i think there are libraries out there with fall back so if a client supports HTML5 sockets they will use the sockets and when there is no support for that .. it will fall back to long polling.

Comment: @zerkms: fine, I proposed the client side, propose the server side now. Everything I will ever say here for you will be wrong. At least I helped the OP in some way :)

Comment: @Naveed Ahmad: how is it helpful to OP?

Comment: @briosheje: please go through the conversation and see that I'm discussing details of server-side with OP while you're making noise with "you don't need it" and with articles that barely help OP with their real problem.

Comment: @Briosheje after 20 seconds a perform it again if there are no results. No just after 1 second which stresses the server.

Comment: @Akar: so how will you maintain the connection for 20 seconds? What will you do on the server during those 20 seconds?

Comment: While loop, If there are any new results, Break and start again.

Comment: @Akar: so during those 20 seconds you will constantly perform the same query? Do you realize it may easily be 1000 queries in total per a client per 20 seconds?

Comment: Nope! If you have better alternative please post it. I have to go, I think I'm late for school. :/ :(